# Auto Call Function When Input Field Has Value

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to implement auto call function when input field has value. When input field has value it can auto call function. But I don't know how to make it work. I provide simple code and [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iuxjqj) as your reference.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pb-1">
  <input maxlength="10" placeholder="Text" (ngModelChange)="didModify(event)" (input)="didModify()" [(ngModel)]="text1">
</div>
<p>{{changeCounter}}</p>
```

**Component**

```
  text1 = 'test count';
  changeCounter = 0;

  didModify() {
    this.changeCounter = this.changeCounter + 1;
    return this.changeCounter;
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by detech?

Comment: Sorry.. sorry.. I mean auto call function..

Comment: when input field has value..it will auto call function() without me to type any value

Comment: @HameedSyed do you clear?

Comment: Did you tried calling the function onInit?

Comment: the (ngModelChange)="eventHandler()" will fire before the value bound to [(ngModel)]="value" is changed. while the (change)="eventHandler()" will fire after the value bound to [(ngModel)]="value" is changed.

Comment: @JadavPalak Thank you so much for your explanation.. ok.. I understood..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to implent OnInit and then you can do it. Please check below code.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  text1 = 'test count';
  changeCounter = 1;
  ngOnInit() { this.didModify(); }

  didModify() {
    this.changeCounter = this.changeCounter + 1;
    return this.changeCounter;
  }
}
```